# Question Regarding creating time period/intervals in R?

Tags: r, time, intervals, lubridate, duration

I have an issue with creating a time period in R.

The data that I have on hand is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xtvwm.png)

Now I want to do the following.

Identify the hour intervals between start and end time and create a list

Identify the hour intervals b/n start and the break time

Finally, remove the break intervals to find the total time

and then create an output.

Could you please assist me?

Comment: Please follow the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag when posting.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what exactly  you need, but from what i understand here is something to get you going:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date


t <- tibble(
  place = "xyz", 
  st = "9:00", 
  et = "13:00"
)


t  <- t %>% 
  mutate(stdur = period_to_seconds(hm(st))) %>% 
  mutate(etdur = period_to_seconds(hm(et))) %>% 
  mutate(interval = dseconds(etdur - stdur)) %>% 
  mutate(interval_hours = seconds_to_period(interval))


glimpse(t)
#> Observations: 1
#> Variables: 7
#> $ place          <chr> "xyz"
#> $ st             <chr> "9:00"
#> $ et             <chr> "13:00"
#> $ stdur          <dbl> 32400
#> $ etdur          <dbl> 46800
#> $ interval       <Duration> 14400s (~4 hours)
#> $ interval_hours <Period> 4H 0M 0S
Created on 2020-02-10 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)
```